# Jumping Pagination for AWS S3 Bucket object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pagination

the pagination here is bit more flexible compared to other questions asked

Suppose I have 100 objects and on the UI I have a pagination component that shows 10 objects each page.
[image]

To be able to jump to any page, currently in backend, I need to fetch all 100 objects and slice the needed range of array and return to UI. However, it results in extra cost of data tranfer and processing.

I thought of few ways, e.g. caching the whole list, but didnt figure out a way to efficiently let my backend be notified by new changes (can not get rid of possibilities of stale reads by just polling the API within some intervals).

Is there a way to just get a given index range of objects? is that possible solely relying on existing APIs?

I posted this question in aws-sdk-java repo on github, but unfortunately until now no response is given.

Comment: No, it is not possible to call `ListObjects()` for a "given range". It can be called with a Prefix, but not for "objects 30 to 39" (as an example). Each `ListObjects()` API call can return a maximum of 1000 objects. So, you're fine for up to 1000 objects. After that, you will need to make multiple calls to discover how many objects there are (or, how many there are for a given Prefix).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thanks for specifying that out. So, e.g. in a scenario where I have 1000 objects in total, Do I need to fetch 1000 objects and 'slice' the result to a specified range for every jumping (say to 300-399, and another request from 600-699)? If I may concern about the price and performance here, is there any conventional practice?

Comment: If you do not wish to cache the object listing, then you would need to make an API call for each page refresh. Since you only have 1000 objects, you can retrieve the entire list of objects in one API call, and 'slice' it in memory. I don't think the API call would be any faster if requesting less than 1000 objects, but you could test it -- let us know what you find!

Comment: @JohnRotenstein indeed the difference of process time between e.g. 600 and 1k objects is subtle. Until now I guess that in general case, if I want A objects starting at index X, I would send X%1000 api calls and slice the result [X, X + A] in memory.  That being said, it is without caching. What's your thoought about caching? My idea is a combination of a call to fetch all objects timeouts daily and a button that calls the fetch api to cache the latest result. So that user can either rely on the daily result (dont care about stale read), or click the button if they need a fresh read.

Comment: It really depends on how often the data is updated. For example, here on StackOverflow questions are added continuously throughout the day. If you use the Search function, it will show results and offer pagination. Clicking "Next" will sometimes repeat a Question because new questions have been added since the results were originally fetched. Thus, I can see that they are performing the Search each time, and are paginating the results (without caching the results). It really comes down to whether you think a cache is acceptable in your application.

Comment: True, this is the tradeoff here. At least now with ur help I know that a given range in listObject is not possible. I will go back to the use case and make a choice given our design requirement. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use the [V2 version of ListObjects](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/model/ListObjectsV2Request.Builder.html), there is a parameter startAfter. You could try using startAfter to get the page you are looking for, without having to fetch the whole list. It doesn't solve all of your problems but it could help with the "fetch a given range" issue.